# Load script on page template

Tags: javascript, wordpress, header

I have a wordpress powered site and my header is contained in the file `header.php`. On a different page I would like to run a script, which is only needed on that page.

The script should be loaded in the header of this page, but this page only. Including the script in the `header.php` would load the script on every other page.

How would I best include the script in the `page-pageslug.php` template?

Comment: Just to clarify - you have a slightly muddled question/title here.  If you only want the script included in a specific page you'd use @stealthyninja's answer. If you want it only on a specific page template you'd use mine (for example if you decided to use that template on another page later and wanted your script included there too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `header.php` above `wp_head();`, use

```
if ( is_page( 'page-slug' ) ) {
    wp_register_script( 'your-script', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/your-script.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script' );
}
```

*`page-slug`* is then the slug of the page you wish to target.

**[`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)**:

> **Description**
>   The safe and recommended method of adding JavaScript to a WordPress generated page is by using wp_enqueue_script(). This function includes the script if it hasn't already been included, and safely handles dependencies.

Comment: Do I need to include `wp_enqueue_script`? What is its (practical) function?

Comment: If you wish to include a JavaScript file, then yes; I've added it's description from the Codex as well as a link to it for your reference.

Comment: Does "handles dependencies" mean it automatically apply something like `jQuery.noConflict();`? At the moment I am including this trick by hand, so that the resulting page works fine with multiple scripts...

Comment: @user1205935 -- No, it means you can make the script dependent on jQuery, jQuery UI or any other script which you (or WordPress itself) have previously registered or included.

Answer (score 0):

You would include the following code in your header.php file

```
<?php 
if ( is_page_template('page-pageslug.php') ) {
   // add your script in here
}
?>
```

Here's the reference from the Codex - [is_page_template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template)